# Java 2d Games with Java SWING

Tags: java, swing, 2d

Me and my friend started developing a game just like Zelda for SNES using **Java**. The only problem is that we don't know what to use: our very own engine with AWT or if we could use SWING to make it easier.

So.. the short question is:

**For soft java-2d games, is it a good or a bad idea to use Java Swing?**

And **WHY?**

Consider that the game is not "heavy".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Bad:** Because you'll just being re-doing all the work someone else has already done (for a 2d game library, perhaps one that uses Swing internally) :-) Swing aimed to replace AWT -- not to be a game library.

Comment: The final boss should be JButton ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have attempted this a few times and found that:

- If your graphics are all unrotated (or quadrant-rotated) sprites and fixed or tiled background images, it is usually fast enough.
- If you need to rotate images or draw geometric shapes (with `Graphics2D`), forget it.  It can slow to a crawl with just 20-30 polygon vertices on the screen.  If you do a lot of rotation & scaling then you are probably better off with a 3D framework, even for a 2D world.

If you do choose swing, learn to use the [BufferStrategy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) class.

Also consider [PulpCore](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/).

Answer (score 2):

While you could use the Java awt and swing libraries to build a game, you would probably have an easier time finding a game-specific library and building around that. Processing is a great choice, especially for beginners. http://processing.org/